# Reducing downtime to zero on jetty server with Chef

Tags: java, jetty, chef-infra

So as I started deploying my web app with jetty server, I noticed there is about a 10 second downtime whenever I redeploy the web app after making some changes.  I know there is a solution out there,  I have found some good leads such as this [one](https://github.com/rafaelsteil/jetty-zero-downtime-deploy/blob/master/jetty_deploy.sh).  However since i am using chef i am not sure how to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

The link you have provided is a bash script. Check out chef's own [bash resource](http://docs.opscode.com/resource_bash.html).
Using bash resource, you can a run a shell script via chef.

This is handy as you already have a script to do what you want to do. So run that script via chef. Of course, there might be a chef specific cookbook/recipe/attribute lying somewhere written. But bash resource is the quickest possible way in this regard to do what you want to do (presuming the bash script you referred is all you need to get the job done).

**UPDATE:**
Check out [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19222641/1251660) where I got something done for which a chef resource does not exists